# Extracting the offset value from a ISO-8601 string in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

With `NSDateFormatter`, if I pass in an ISO-8601 date+time value with an offset, it will read the offset and adjust the output to a UTC value, like so:

```
// Setup
let formatter        = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale     = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"

// Test
let input     = "2016-04-16 04:12:00-0800"
let output    = formatter.dateFromString( input )
let outputStr = formatter.stringFromDate( output )
print( outputStr ) // "2016-04-15 08:12:00-0000"
```

So far, so good.

But I want to get at that offset value myself. My application is a client for a webservice which preserves date-time offset information, so I must do the same (as if I blindly return `outputStr` to the webservice, it will have lost the offset information so the database won't know what the offset was when the datetime was collected.

`NSDateFormatter` only seems to accept timezone information for outputting dates, there's no way for me to get the numeric offset out of an input string.

Answer (score 1):

'self explanatory' example

```
import Foundation

let formatter        = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale     = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"

// Test
let input     = "2016-04-16 04:12:00-0800"
let output    = formatter.dateFromString( input )

// with curent time zone (system default
let outputStrL = formatter.stringFromDate( output! )

// with time zone Z+0000
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
let outputStr = formatter.stringFromDate( output! )

// with time zone Z-0800
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: -8 * 3600)
let outputStr1 = formatter.stringFromDate( output! )

print("My local time:", outputStrL)
print("GMT+0000 time:", outputStr)
print("GMT-0800 tume:", outputStr1)

/*
 My local time: 2016-04-16 14:12:00+0200
 GMT+0000 time: 2016-04-16 12:12:00+0000
 GMT-0800 tume: 2016-04-16 04:12:00-0800
 */
```

if you replace the input string with any of output strings (outputStr, outputStrL, outputStr1), NSDate created from it represents the same value (time)

Comment: Your example does not show how I can get the timezone offset from a given string date+time value.

Comment: ?? your input string represents specific time value, the SAME VALUE can be represented as string with different time offsets.

Comment: do you want just 'parse' the input string and take -0800 from it? or do you need the time which it represents?

Comment: by the way, it has nothing with locale, you can remove that line from the code (for this specific .dateFormat, which doesn't include any locale specific information)